# Closed alpha testing tracks how to differentiate between two test tracks?

Tags: android

We are using Google Play [Alpah testing tracks](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en#create_additional_track) which can be tested by different testing teams for their respective modules.

But the links generated by these tracks are same how to get an application for a member which may be added to multiple closed alpha testing tracks.

e.g. We have two tracks `Alpha Track 1` and `Alpha Track` 2, we have few common tester emails in these two but most of them get the apk from `Alpha Track 1` which is the first created track. How can they install apk from `Alpha Track 2` from their testing email accounts? Or do they need to have totally different email id for each track?

Comment: Over the top of my head (obviously, not an official source:): 1) testers do not need to have different e-mail addresses; 2) those in both tracks will get the app from the track which has the higher app version code.

Comment: @ozbek what your saying makes sense, But why there is no any official documentation about the behaviour of the test tracks except how to create it?

Comment: Probably, because this is not a common case. Please contact Google Play support team, I am sure they will confirm what I said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google just updated their help center documentation regarding this. See [Version codes & testing track statuses](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en#availability) section (emphasis is mine):

> ### Version code requirements
>
> Users receive the version of the app that has:
>
> - The highest version code that’s compatible with their device, and
> - Been published to a track they're eligible to receive
>
> All users are always eligible to receive the production track. If an APK with a higher version code is published in production than in the test track where the user opted in, the user will receive the production APK.
>
> ***Users eligible to receive multiple tracks will receive the highest version code APK published on those tracks.***
>
> For a user to be eligible to receive a test track, the user must:
>
> - Be included in the managed track configuration, and
> - Have opted in to the corresponding test program
>
> For example, all users who opted in to the test program are eligible for the open test track. Users who opted in to the internal test program are not eligible for the open and closed test tracks, even if they're included in the managed testers configuration. These users would not receive higher version code APKs published on those tracks.
>
> For more information, learn about [versioning your apps](https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, I've just tried to use this and it doesn't appear to be working as I would expect. I've had one closed track (the original Alpha one), I created a new closed track and turned that on for one of my lists. I released an apk on to the new track, with a higher version code, but no-one on that list can see the new apk in the play store. I've even deselected that list from the Alpha track. Any ideas?

Comment: Have the users in the new list accepted the invitation for the test?

Comment: I got it working. They had to cancel the original accept and then accept again